How to publish new custom form to all users of site in SharePoint designer 2019
The custom form I'm using in SharePoint Designer 2019 is currently only accessible to administrators, as it shows an "Access Denied" error to regular users. In designer, the custom forms show blue icon to the left and contains the letter 'i'.
I would like for all users to be able to access and use this custom form, similar to how the default form is visible to everyone. However, I'm finding that this functionality is only available for the default form, not the custom one.
I've tried to investigate the option to publish the form or list through the /layouts/sitemanager.aspx page, but I couldn't locate that setting.
Could you please advise on how I can grant access permissions to allow all users to view and use the custom new/edit form? Do I need to publish the form pages separately to make them visible to users?

I noticed that my site users did not have read/contribute permission for lists. So, I added those permissions and my problem was resolved.
For my custom access to data from form, I added a JavaScript cod to restrict viewing of page to those particular users only.

This icon means that the page is not published and are in checked out mode. publish using SPD or your can run powershell code to publish the page.

How can I publish SPD? I cannot find this option for list form .aspx files. I checked layouts/sitemanager.aspx and still could not find it.
